# Downloading file using Asp.Net IHttpHandler gives different file property results

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written an IHttpHandler that extracts querystring parameters, and uses them to determine what type of file do send back.  In the handler I call:

```
private static void GetSegmentFile(HttpContext context)
{
    byte[] file = GetFile();
    context.Response.ContentyType = "application/octet-stream";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(file);
}
```

On the browser side I get different results when trying to download the file (using right click > save as on a link in a web page web with it's href set to the file's URL).  using a test.docx these are my results:

Chrome:  File has the original file name and file extension
IE 11: File is renamed to `media` with the `.zip` file extension.

I have attached an image to show what I mean.[image]

Comment: I believe your two files are different (browser and code). Make sure the two paths are identical

Comment: you couldn't make the explorer windows a bit smaller for your screenshot? :P

Comment: Right click on what? How are you downloading? Btw. Arent't you lacking the Content-Disposition header?

Comment: @WiktorZychla By right clicking on an `<a>` element that has its href set to the file's URL

Comment: Then you definitely lack the `Content-Disposition : attachment; filename=foo.docx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a `Content-Disposition` HTTP header. You can send a file name that way. IE tried to interpret the bytes you sent and found that it is a zip file. Office documents are zip files with a different extension.

Chrome apparently used the URL to heuristically construct a name.

Without an explicit name what is the browser supposed to do? It can only guess.

Research the proper way to use that HTTP header to send a file name and specify a name.